# EdX course with multiple languages

Tags: edx

we are developping a course with EdX. This course will be in french, canadian french and swiss french. How does EdX manage multiple languages for a course ? 
So far, we thought we would manage this by creating three courses (french version, canadian version, swiss version). But we are not very happy with this quick fix.

Also, it would be preferable if the student could set his language when enrolling and be directly on the course with his language.

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: The mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/edx-code) will be a better place to get help.

Comment: I've recently run into the same issue. All I can say is that Open EdX's internationalization implementation does not behave as I would expect (i.e. localizing the site based on the browser's Accept-Language value.) Upon speaking with a reputable contractor that specializes in Open EdX implementations. This contractor's solution is to setup a separate Open EdX instance for each language.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article is the best vision I found: https://help.appsembler.com/article/465-multilingual-courses

But keep this in mind: "There is no cost-free, simple, push-button way to deliver the same course in another language without sacrificing quality."

I'm working on a project that will have to address this issue, I update here with the solution.